# Debugger compile handler overriden, will not be active in this request

Tags: php, remote-debugging, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I have Zend Debugger setup on the server and trying to remote debug from Zend Studio client. It doesn't work and I get this in the server error log:

> [Zend Debugger] Debugger compile handler overriden, will not be active in this request

What's the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The debugger is very finicky about any PHP extensions enabled. I was receiving the same `[Zend Debugger] Debugger compile handler overriden, will not be active in this request` error on the Apache error log on Mac OS X with MAMP and PHP 5.2.x. Disabling the Zend Optimizer and XCache from the MAMP control panel resolved this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can load Xdebug as an extension to have Xdebug and Zend Debugger installed at the same time. This allows you to debug with Zend Debugger while still getting some of the features of Xdebug (formatted errors, for example).

```
extension=/wherever/you/put/it/xdebug.so
zend_extension= /wherever/you/put/it/ZendDebugger.so
```

http://xdebug.org/docs/faq#php-ext

### phpinfo()

```
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies
  with Zend Debugger v5.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2010, by Zend Technologies
  with Xdebug v2.1.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: Adding extension=/where/you/put/it/xdebug.so fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running a LAMP stack on Ubuntu, and I had to disable OPCache to get Zend Debugger to work. I did this in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

```
opcache.enable=0
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason was that I had XDebug also installed on the server and zend debugger conflicts with xdebug. remove XDebug. to verify that zend debugger is loaded and XDebug is not run phpinfo() and verify in the output

Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Debugger v5.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2010, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.0.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2008, by Derick Rethans

that you do have the Zend Debugger line but DO NOT have the Xdebug line.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old link, but I came across the same error message when installing Zend Server 2019.0.  It ships with multiple PHP versions, latest being 7.3.2.  I corrected the issue when switched back to 7.2.15, then everything worked fine out of the box.